# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.CookieSignatureSecretFactory

Tags: hadoop, authentication

I am getting this issue. I got to know this Class is there in hadoop auth. I tried with 2.2 and 2.6 versions both. But still the error persists.
But I cant see it.

I got this error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/server/CookieSignatureSecretFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:295)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProperties(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:113)
    at com.aexp.esp.reports.center.HbaseClientReports.<init>(HbaseClientReports.java:19)
    at com.aexp.esp.reports.center.ReportCenter.initializeReportCenter(ReportCenter.java:58)
    at com.aexp.esp.reports.center.ReportCenter.main(ReportCenter.java:308)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.CookieSignatureSecretFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${your.hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```